# Unable to pair bluetooth keyboard on Arch Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, bluetooth, arch-linux, wireless-keyboard

I'm currently unable to pair my [BT60v2](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) on Arch Linux. I have however been able to pair it previously, but now I'm unable to. I'm able to pair the keyboard just fine to my phone.

Things I've tried:

- Clear bluetooth profile on keyboard
- Flash default firmware to keyboard
- Deleted `/var/lib/bluetooth`
- Switched from `bluez` to `bluez-git`

In between attempts I have removed the device, scanned, trusted it, and then attempted to re-pair. Any ideas of what to try next? I always get the same error.

`bluetoothctl pair <MAC>`:

```
Attempting to pair with F5:12:39:30:1D:EB
[CHG] Device F5:12:39:30:1D:EB Connected: yes
Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationFailed
```

`dmesg | grep Bluetooth`:

```
[16882.418167] Bluetooth: hci0: unexpected SMP command 0x0b from f5:12:39:30:1d:be
```

`btmon`:

```
@ MGMT Command: Pair Device (0x0019) plen 8                                                                     {0x0001} [hci0] 2.158407
        LE Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Capability: KeyboardDisplay (0x04)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) plen 8                                                   #1 [hci0] 2.158426
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Filter policy: Ignore not in accept list (0x01)
        PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Type: Passive (0x00)
          Interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                           #2 [hci0] 2.273191
      LE Set Extended Scan Parameters (0x08|0x0041) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                                                       #3 [hci0] 2.273284
        Extended scan: Enabled (0x01)
        Filter duplicates: Enabled (0x01)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                           #4 [hci0] 2.275192
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 45                                                                             #5 [hci0] 2.298224
      LE Extended Advertising Report (0x0d)
        Num reports: 1
        Entry 0
          Event type: 0x0013
            Props: 0x0013
              Connectable
              Scannable
              Use legacy advertising PDUs
            Data status: Complete
          Legacy PDU Type: ADV_IND (0x0013)
          Address type: Random (0x01)
          Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
          Primary PHY: LE 1M
          Secondary PHY: No packets
          SID: no ADI field (0xff)
          TX power: 127 dBm
          RSSI: -54 dBm (0xca)
          Periodic advertising interval: 0.00 msec (0x0000)
          Direct address type: Public (0x00)
          Direct address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (OUI 00-00-00)
          Data length: 0x13
        05 09 42 54 36 30 03 19 c1 03 02 01 06 05 02 12  ..BT60..........
        18 0f 18                                         ...             
        Name (complete): BT60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
< HCI Command: LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) plen 6                                                       #6 [hci0] 2.298316
        Extended scan: Disabled (0x00)
        Filter duplicates: Disabled (0x00)
        Duration: 0 msec (0x0000)
        Period: 0.00 sec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Complete (0x0e) plen 4                                                                           #7 [hci0] 2.303159
      LE Set Extended Scan Enable (0x08|0x0042) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
< HCI Command: LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) plen 26                                                    #8 [hci0] 2.303213
        Filter policy: Accept list is not used (0x00)
        Own address type: Public (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Initiating PHYs: 0x01
        Entry 0: LE 1M
          Scan interval: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Scan window: 60.000 msec (0x0060)
          Min connection interval: 30.00 msec (0x0018)
          Max connection interval: 50.00 msec (0x0028)
          Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
          Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
          Min connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
          Max connection length: 0.000 msec (0x0000)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                             #9 [hci0] 2.315135
      LE Extended Create Connection (0x08|0x0043) ncmd 2
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 31                                                                            #10 [hci0] 2.409188
      LE Enhanced Connection Complete (0x0a)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585
        Role: Central (0x00)
        Peer address type: Random (0x01)
        Peer address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Local resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Peer resolvable private address: 00:00:00:00:00:00 (Non-Resolvable)
        Connection interval: 45.00 msec (0x0024)
        Connection latency: 0 (0x0000)
        Supervision timeout: 420 msec (0x002a)
        Central clock accuracy: 0x00
@ MGMT Event: Device Connected (0x000b) plen 32                                                                 {0x0001} [hci0] 2.409261
        LE Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Flags: 0x00000008
          Connection Locally Initiated
        Data length: 19
        Name (complete): BT60
        Appearance: Keyboard (0x03c1)
        Flags: 0x06
          LE General Discoverable Mode
          BR/EDR Not Supported
        16-bit Service UUIDs (partial): 2 entries
          Human Interface Device (0x1812)
          Battery Service (0x180f)
< HCI Command: LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) plen 2                                                     #11 [hci0] 2.409383
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
@ RAW Open: btmon (privileged) version 2.22                                                                            {0x0002} 2.409538
@ RAW Close: btmon                                                                                                     {0x0002} 2.409552
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 4                                                                             #12 [hci0] 2.410126
      LE Channel Selection Algorithm (0x14)
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Algorithm: #2 (0x01)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                            #13 [hci0] 2.414129
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x08|0x0016) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 6                                                                         #14 [hci0] 2.416633
      SMP: Security Request (0x0b) len 1
        Authentication requirement: Bonding, No MITM, SC, No Keypresses (0x09)
> HCI Event: LE Meta Event (0x3e) plen 12                                                                            #15 [hci0] 2.462142
      LE Read Remote Used Features (0x04)
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Features: 0x7f 0x41 0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
          LE Encryption
          Connection Parameter Request Procedure
          Extended Reject Indication
          Peripheral-initiated Features Exchange
          LE Ping
          LE Data Packet Length Extension
          LL Privacy
          LE 2M PHY
          Channel Selection Algorithm #2
          Minimum Number of Used Channels Procedure
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 11                                                                        #16 [hci0] 2.462193
      SMP: Pairing Request (0x01) len 6
        IO capability: KeyboardDisplay (0x04)
        OOB data: Authentication data not present (0x00)
        Authentication requirement: Bonding, MITM, SC, No Keypresses, CT2 (0x2d)
        Max encryption key size: 16
        Initiator key distribution: EncKey Sign LinkKey (0x0d)
        Responder key distribution: EncKey IdKey Sign LinkKey (0x0f)
< ACL Data TX: Handle 3585 flags 0x00 dlen 7                                                                         #17 [hci0] 2.462289
      ATT: Exchange MTU Request (0x02) len 2
        Client RX MTU: 517
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                               #18 [hci0] 2.507153
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 6                                                                         #19 [hci0] 2.507609
      SMP: Pairing Failed (0x05) len 1
        Reason: Authentication requirements (0x03)
@ MGMT Event: Command Complete (0x0001) plen 10                                                                 {0x0001} [hci0] 2.507651
      Pair Device (0x0019) plen 7
        Status: Authentication Failed (0x05)
        LE Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3                                                                       #20 [hci0] 2.507657
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Reason: Authentication Failure (0x05)
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4                                                                            #21 [hci0] 2.508131
      Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) ncmd 1
        Status: Success (0x00)
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5                                                               #22 [hci0] 2.509139
        Num handles: 1
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Count: 1
> ACL Data RX: Handle 3585 flags 0x02 dlen 7                                                                         #23 [hci0] 2.551882
      ATT: Exchange MTU Response (0x03) len 2
        Server RX MTU: 65
> HCI Event: Disconnect Complete (0x05) plen 4                                                                       #24 [hci0] 2.552153
        Status: Success (0x00)
        Handle: 3585 Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Reason: Connection Terminated By Local Host (0x16)
@ MGMT Event: Device Disconnected (0x000c) plen 8                                                               {0x0001} [hci0] 2.552193
        LE Address: F5:12:39:30:1D:EB (Static)
        Reason: Connection terminated by local host (0x02)
```

Comment: Which DE are you using? 

I've had issues paring keyboards via command line but the bluetooth GUI in KDE seems to make it all work.

Comment: Also try adding the keyboard to the bluetooth trust.
According to the [documentation](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth) from Arch Linux devices that don't require a pin to pair sometimes need to trust the device before they can pair

> If using a device without a PIN, one may need to manually trust the device before it can reconnect successfully. Enter bluetoothctl trust MAC_address to do so.

Comment: @Insanemal I'm using i3WM. I have tried pairing using GUI applications (blueman). Also, I have tried trusting it between attempts, but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: I had the same problem with blueman/bluemanctl. `Failed to pair: org.bluez.Error.AuthenticationCanceled` Then I tried `gnome-control-center`, got a button "Do you want to pair?", clicked it, and all was well.